# writing a batch file to input path and filename, get size and date of file, then sort

Tags: batch-file

I have created a file with path and filename. 
I am passing the file names, via the command line, one at a time my batch file.
I am using the %~1, %~t1, %~z1 to obtain the time and size values.
I want to write each record to a file for sorting. The time and file sizes will be different and I want to save the version with the best information.

I am having problems in the batch file to get the size and date. I am trying to test if I get an error reading the information for the file. When I look at the parameter it always contains the path filename passed to the batch file. When printing the %~t1 an %~z1 values if every thing is normal I see the correct values else the print just shows time = and size =. Therefore I am trying to use the file size or time value to determine if there was an error.

I have tried many different ways to use an IF cmd to print out that an ERROR occurred or not. I have not used batch file in a while and I can not figure out what is causing the problems.

This is a snippet from the batch file (with some of the things I have tried):

```
@echo off

rem if [%~z1] == []
rem if [NOT] %~t1
rem if ["%~t1]==[]
rem if exist [%~1] 
 str1 = %~t1
 if not definded str1 (echo str1 error)
 if not definded str1
(   print "AN ERROR OCURRED  FOR THIS FILE/n"  )
else
(   
    echo fpath =%~1 
    echo time = %~t1   
    echo size = %~z1   
)
```

I get:

- ) was unexpected at this time
- The syntax of the command is incorrect
- EXIST was unexpected at this time
- unable to initialize device PRN. 'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command
- str1 is not recognized as an internal or external command, .. str1 was unexpected at this time

These are probably my errors but searching many information sites is not ringing a bell in my head as to what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **definded** is not a word. You're looking to test for **defined** instead, as in `if not defined`.

Comment: PowerShell would make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you are looking for is `if defined`. Definded is not a word.

You must use the `set` command to store a value in a variable, so your first line needs to be `set str1=%~t1`

`if` statements need their `(` on the same line as the `if`. Similarly, `)`, `else`, and `(` must all be on the same line.

`Print` is technically a valid batch command, but it sends documents to the printer; batch uses `echo` to display text to the screen, and newline characters are appended to echoed lines automatically.

```
@echo off
set str1=%~t1

if not defined str1 (
    echo AN ERROR OCCURRED FOR THIS FILE
) else (
    echo fpath=%~1
    echo time=%~t1
    echo size=%~z1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to make it work. I found a post indicating that the brackets need to be in that exact format otherwise it doesn’t work at all. Even putting brackets around the IF part of the statement will stop the script from working as expected.

IF statements on their own are much easier to deal with. To check for an empty argument for example either of the following will work:

if "%~t1" == "" (
    echo "                      AN ERROR OCURRED  FOR THIS FILE/n"
) else (
    echo fpath =%~1 
    echo time = %~t1
    echo size = %~z1
)

Comment: That's literally what I posted 16 hours before you did. Why did you ignore my answer?